# NSBitmapImageRep to NSMutableArray or NSMutableDictionary

Tags: objective-c, opengl, nsmutablearray, nsmutabledictionary, nsbitmapimagerep

Is it possible to store `NSBitmapImageRep` copy to `NSMutableDictionary` or `NSMutableArray`? I need to save copy of OpenGL texture somewhere so, that I could use it later. So if I would do `glReadPixels`, store readed pixels to `NSBitmapImageRep` and somehow store it to `NSMutableDictionary` or `NSMutableArray` will it work? Or maby there are some other ways to do it?

Comment: `NSBitmapImageRep` is an object. What's wrong with just putting it in an array?

Comment: I'm just asking if it would work. Thank you for answer. I'll check it out just right now

Comment: By the way, doesn't array stores only pointers to objects?

Comment: Yes, you can store any `NSObject` descendant in an array or dictionary. That's what they're for. Are you having trouble doing this? *What have you actually tried*?

Comment: For clarification, you can add your object to an array or dictionary for later reference, but this will not create a copy of the object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can store it in an array / dictionary. If you specifically want to make a copy of the bitmap rep before you put it in an array, you can do so.

```
[array addObject:[bitmapRep copy]];
```